# Can we Modify the accessibility of Type-bound Procedures in Fortran

Tags: fortran, procedure, fortran2008

```
MODULE MyTypeMod

TYPE MyType
PRIVATE
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: Num
CONTAINS
  PROCEDURE, PUBLIC :: IsNum!To check Allocation of Num
  ...
END TYPE MyType

CONTAINS
...
END MODULE MyTypeMod
```

```
PROGRAM testMyType
USE MyTypeMod, ONLY : MyType

...
END PROGRAM testMyType
```

Here In this Module and Program, Can we modify accessibility status "IsNum" type-bound procedure? Can we make the "IsNum" procedure PRIVATE in just the testMyTypeMod PROGRAM?

Comment: Did you just try changeng `public` to `private`. That makes it orivate to the module. If that is not what you want, what do you actually exactly want?

Comment: I want the type-bound procedure(IsNum) accessibility status to be PUBLIC to all the Modules/Programs to which it is imported, but for this particular program(testMyType), I want it to be PRIVATE.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: The “USE MyTypeMod, ONLY : ” Will hide it on the main program side if the procedure is not on the only-list..

Comment: @Holmz I believe that only works for regular procedures, not type-bound procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to paragraph `9` of section `7.5.5` of the [Fortran 2018 draft standard](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2018)

> A public type-bound procedure is accessible via any accessible object of the type. A private type-bound procedure is accessible only within the module containing the type definition, and within its descendants.

And so changing the accessibility of a type-bound procedure is not possible.

There is currently [a proposal](https://github.com/j3-fortran/fortran_proposals/issues/127) to update a future Fortran standard that suggests making a subset of what you want to do possible.

You may want to make a new proposal to update the standard. This is also likely the best way to find out why what you want to do is not currently possible.